# Open URL on Bootstrap Modal close

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Maybe I'm brain dead here, but I'm trying to do what seems should be an easy thing.

I am using Bootstrap to open a modal on page load depending on the value of specific variables.  This all works great.  However, when the modal opens and the user clicks ok (presumably after reading the info text), I want to page to redirect to a new page.  I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Any info on how to do

Answer (score 7):

```
$(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
    window.location = "your-url";
});
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage

You could also (and that is probably a better option) add a `onclick` handler to the button that the user has to click (because the `hidden.bs.modal` event also fires when the user closes the modal by pressing `Esc` or clicking the `x` button.

Comment: I believe you mean `window.location` and not `windows.location`

Answer (score 4):

Along the lines of @Knagis additional option, you can use `onclick` to change the window.location, and the `data-dismiss=modal` attribute in the same link..

```
<a href="" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="javascript:window.location='http://google.com'">Visit Google.</a>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/oKgjTJXGTq

Answer (score 0):

it also dismiss the modal , modal should be dismissed after 10-20 seconds or manualy by closing it , is it  possible .