# How to trigger jquery on bootstrap 3 modal close

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a django project with the following hidden modal embedded in the page, which is displayed on form submit:

```
     <div class="modal fade" id="thanksModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header" style="text-align: center">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

                    <h2>Thank you!</h2>
                    </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <h3>We'll get back to you </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
          </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

I'm trying to clear the form by redirecting to my django route on closing of the modal box. Following: [Open URL on Bootstrap Modal close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580978/open-url-on-bootstrap-modal-close) , I added

```
$(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {

    console.log("MODAL CLOSED")  // sanity check
    window.location = "/myroute/";
 });
```

But nothing is happening, and I do not see MODAL CLOSED in the console. How can I get this working?

Comment: do you see any error in the console?

Comment: sorry, no I don't

Comment: strange, i tried your html with boostrap 3.3.7 and it works correctly

Comment: take a look to this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q96ve7La/)

Comment: its working now. I had to restart the server and delete the browser cache.

Comment: Try changing it from `$(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {` to `$("#thanksModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {` and see if that helps your cause.  Maybe you have multiple modals on the page.

Comment: Thank you , it was working on restart of server